# How can I make duplicates of an object using empties as placeholders?

Tags: objects, instances

How can I make duplicates of an object using empties as placeholders? For example I have a cube as original. After that I place some empties with a certain position, rotation and scaling and then turn those empties into duplicates of the original cube?

Answer (score 5):

First select the cube and create a group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Then select all your **empties** and go to the `Properties Panel` > `Object` > `Duplication` click `Group` and then choose the newly created group from the dropdown.

[image: Add group instance to empty]

If you have selected more than one **empty**, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> with all of them selected and click on `DupliGroup` to have the Group property copied to all of them.